# "After class" vs "after classes."

Tags: word-choice, grammar

Which expression is more commmon? Do they mean the same thing?

Example:

> After class/classes the next day, I went to play with my friends.

Comment: I'm in the US, and I would say "after classes" would be rare and "after class" more common.  But maybe elsewhere the preference is the other way.

Comment: In the UK, a teacher would say "see me after class", for when the lesson had ended. I would understand "see me after classes" as being the end of the school day, but as GEdgar says, it's not common. I can't think of a common expression that uses "after classes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you say "after class", this means after a particular lecture/period, and when its "after classes" this means after the school is over or when all classes are over.